# Paypal Preapproval invalid request

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying to play with the PreApproval from Adaptive Payments. Specifically, to go through the four steps from [the documentation on Preapproval](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicPreapproval-curl-etc/).

I'm stuck at the `Step 1: Set Up the Preapproval` with a curl command:

```
$ curl -s --insecure \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: myuserid.gmail.com" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: mypass" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: mysignaturestring" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-80W284485P519543T" \
https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Preapproval  -d \
  "cancelUrl=http://www.yourdomain.com/cancel.html
  &currencyCode=USD
  &endingDate=2014-09-10T22:00:00Z
  &maxAmountPerPayment=200.00
  &maxNumberOfPayments=30
  &maxTotalAmountOfAllPayments=1500.00
  &pinType=NOT_REQUIRED
  &requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US
  &returnUrl=http://www.yourdomain.com/success.html
  &startingDate=2014-08-10T22:00:00Z"
```

Instead of a `preapprovalKey`, I receive an error. I know it's something wrong with the data I send, but I can't figure out what:

```
esponseEnvelope.timestamp=2014-08-05T01:24:55.289-07:00
&responseEnvelope.ack=Failure
&responseEnvelope.correlationId=7c6db7beda57a
&responseEnvelope.build=11853342
&error(0).errorId=580001
&error(0).domain=PLATFORM
&error(0).subdomain=Application
&error(0).severity=Error
&error(0).category=Application
&error(0).message=Invalid request: Data validation warning(line -1, col 0): 2014-09-10T22:00:00Z
&error(0).parameter(0)=Data validation warning(line -1, col 0): 2014-09-10T22:00:00Z
```

Please note that:

- my API credentials are OK, I've successfully tested them on `Express Checkout` from [the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-singleItemPayment-curl-etc/)
- some fields are according to [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/) while others are exactly like in the docs copy pasted:

  - `startingDate` is in the future, the docs say to not be today's date (the date of the post) or after end date.
  - `endingDate - startingDate` is one month, less than a year as they say in the docs.
  - I also tried using https://apigee.com/console/paypal in case I was doing sth wrong with curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damn, I figured it out due to my indentation on SO to have it look pretty for you guys. It's because of the whitespace enters (`\n`'s) in the `-d \ "cancelUrl=... &currencyCode=USD & ..."`.

Thanks, so the correct one for reference here is:

```
$ curl -s --insecure \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: myuserid.gmail.com" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: mypass" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: mysignaturestring" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-80W284485P519543T" \
https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Preapproval  -d \
  "cancelUrl=http://www.yourdomain.com/cancel.html&currencyCode=USD&endingDate=2014-09-10T22:00:00Z&maxAmountPerPayment=200.00&maxNumberOfPayments=30&maxTotalAmountOfAllPayments=1500.00&pinType=NOT_REQUIRED&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US&returnUrl=http://www.yourdomain.com/success.html&startingDate=2014-08-10T22:00:00Z"
```